# Availability Group is not failovering when a cluster core resource is failedover

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, failover, role

I have created always on availability group.The cluster core resources failover is happening. The availability group (Automatic) failover is happening. But, when the cluster core resource is failed over the availability group failover is not triggered.

For example,in cluster core resource server1 is online and in AG server1 is primary replica.
When the cluster core resource is failed over to server2, the AG is still in server1 as primary replica.

Why is that happening? The AG role is healthy.Please help me here.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cluster core resource can be primary in one of the nodes without affecting the singles AGs and their assignament to a specific node. It is different from a Failover cluster Instance where there is dependency from the cluster core resource and the clustered service.

I suggest you to manage AG failover inside ssms moving then with the proper wizard or by tsql query command.

Plase take a look at this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/perform-a-planned-manual-failover-of-an-availability-group-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank You @MBuschi. Able to perform manual failover in SSMS. So, the cluster core resource failover does not affect AG failover?

Comment: It depends if it comes because a node went down or only a manual movement of the cluster core resource.

Comment: So, if the manual cluster core resource failover is performed - then there is no affect on AG. If the primary node went down in WSFC, then the AG failover also should takes place?

Comment: Exact, this is the behavoir

Comment: Thank You @MBuschi.You helped me at perfect time.